# How to change click event dynamically in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

When the B component finishes loading, I send an "emit" event to the A component via EventBus.

And when event received from A component is "on", it changes the value of specific data to true.

The value is registered in computed and can only be used with "a tag" if the value is true.

But actually the value changes to true but the click event still returns "return false;"

How to make click event behave dynamically in VueJS?

**B Component**

```
...
this.$EventBus.$emit("Loading");
...
```

**A Component**

```
<template>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" @click="completed ? btnFinish : 'return false;'">Complete</a>
</template>
<script>
    data() {
        return {
            loading: false,
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.$EventBus.$on('Loading', ()=>{
            this.loading = true;
        });
    },
    computed: {
        completed() {
            return this.loading
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: How do you know it *'returns "return false;"'*? What is `btnFinish`?

Comment: btnFinish () is a method to operate.

If "return false;", nothing happens when clicked, but console.log () is shown by default if it works as a method.

So, even if this.loading is changed to true, the click event still returns "return false;".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you've misunderstood what this `click` listener is doing:

```
@click="completed ? btnFinish : 'return false;'"
```

Firstly, the `'return false;'` part is doing nothing but filling the space after the colon. You could just as easily write `null`, or change it to an `&&` instead of a `?:`.

Next up, the value for an `@` listener can either be a function or an expression. So for example, something like this would be passing a function:

```
@click="btnFinish"
```

When you pass a function it will be treated as the handler for the event.

However, that isn't what you're doing. You're passing an expression. When you pass an expression it gets wrapped in a function behind the scenes by Vue. So when you write something like this:

```
@click="completed ? btnFinish : 'return false;'"
```

Vue will compile that down to a listener function like this:

```js
function ($event) {
  return completed ? btnFinish : 'return false;'
}
```

Note that `btnFinish` refers to a method but it doesn't invoke it. So to get this working we need to put in the parentheses:

```
@click="completed ? btnFinish() : 'return false;'"
```

Or even better:

```
@click="completed && btnFinish()"
```

Or better still, move the whole thing into a method:

```
@click="onClick"
```

```js
methods: {
  onClick () {
    if (this.completed) {
      this.btnFinish()
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there is another way
first, find button from the id

```
 const iButton = document.getElementById('buttonId');
 iButton.onclick = newmethod
```